# How can the relationship of these objects be modelled, so that when given a set of objects I can determine what other objects are compatible?

Tags: design-patterns

Consider the follow entities:

`Bob`, `Sally`, `Apples`, `Oranges`, `SupermarketA`, `SupermarketB`.

The relationship between this is as follows:

- `Bob` can buy `Apples` from `SupermarketA` and `SupermarketB`
- `Bob` can buy `Oranges` from `SupermarketA`
- `Sally` can buy `Apples` from `SupermarketA` and `SupermarketB`
- `Sally` can buy `Oranges` from `SupermarketA` and `SupermarketB`

How can I answer the question:

Who can buy `Oranges` from `SupermarketB`?

I have tried to create these relationships in a graph. However when traversing this graph Bob can buy `Oranges` from `SupermarketB` because `Sally` can:

`Bob` <-> `Oranges` <-> `SupermarketA`

`Sally` <-> `Oranges` <-> `SupermarketA`

`Sally` <-> `Oranges` <-> `SupermarketB`

An alternative approach I have tried is adding these in a 3-dimensional array of booleans as a lookup so that you can determine if `Bob` can buy `Oranges` from `SupermarketB` by indexing to `lookup[0][1][1] = false`. You can find the answer for `Sally` by indexing to `lookup[1][1][1] = true`, or to answer the original question, iterate over the first dimension looking `[*][1][1]`.

The lookup approach seems quite wasteful, especially with more dimensions.

How can I effectively model these relationships so I can determine the compatibility between a given set of entities?

Answer (score 2):

The lookup approach isn't that wasteful. I've done it with hash tables (nesting lets you set up N-way associations). I've done it with indexed fields in a database table. Speed is rarely an issue.

But if the lookup approach isn't good enough, If you're looking for something statically checked at compile time you'll need a language that supports [Multiple Dispatch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_dispatch). But that only works with types. Supermarket B seems more like an instance of supermarket than a type.

Rather then limit your design to a function that returns bools I'd encourage one that also allows you to give 2 and get a list of the related 3rd.

Answer (score 1):

To model the relations between your Buyers (`Bob`, `Sally`), Suppliers (`Supermarket A`, `Supermarket B`) and Products (`Apples`, `Oranges`), you need a three-way association.

Most programming languages can't represent N-way associations (with N>2), so you will need a separate class to represent the association, giving something like

```
Buyer <-> BuyAt <-> Product
            ^
            |
            v
        Supplier
```

If you now ask "Who can buy `Oranges` at `Supermarket B`?", you can get all the BuyAt records related to `Supermarket B`, filter them for `Oranges` and get the answer that only `Sally` can buy `Oranges` at `Supermarket B`.

Comment: Thanks @bart-van-ingen-schenau, that's a good design! So here we ensure N is always equal to 2 and then we can easily create the relationships via BuyAt records. Can you suggest how I would extend this such that “Bob” can buy “Apples” at “SupermarketA” on “Tuesday” when “Full Moon on Monday” such that N = 5?

Would we simply have 5 spokes?

Comment: @c-py, yes, then you would have 5 spokes (1 extra for the weekday and 1 extra for the phase of the moon).

Answer (score 0):

Far from being wasteful, a simple indexed lookup table which stores permissible or impermissible purchases is probably the simplest and most flexible approach to this.